# Upload file using FTP and register under EDD folder

Tags: wordpress, easy-digital-downloads

Is there any way to upload files using ftp and register under EDD folder?
I tried to upload .zip file directly into the edd folder but after upload this file not showing into the media library.

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to upload directly via FTP its not an issue.

But, you are placing it under EDD folder which is no where associated with Media Library for WordPress. So, in this scenario its not possible with WordPress.